# How to safely check type of superglobal POST['key']?

Tags: php

How can i safely check the type of superglobal post[key]?
For instance, i have the following code:

```
$ufo = false;
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'key')) {

    if (is_string($_POST['key'])) { // <- IS THIS SAFE?

        $ufo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    } elseif (is_array($_POST['key'])) { // <- IS THIS SAFE?

        $ufo = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    }
}
```

Is there a safer way to check the type of the posted variable?

Comment: safe for/against what exactly? What do you use the variables for after that?

Comment: This is probably more fit to be in code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types of the external variables will always be string or array, as described on http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#language.variables.determining-type-of:

> HTTP being a text protocol, most, if not all, content that comes in Superglobal arrays, like `$_POST` and `$_GET` will remain as strings. PHP will not try to convert values to a specific type.

When you check your variable against the types "string" and "array" you handled all the possible types.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `isset()` function together with whatever checks you want to do will make it 'safer', since your code doesn't get broken if the variable or index is not set or defined.

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

In that regard, you may rewrite your code as follows:

```
$ufo = false;
if (isset($_POST['key'])) {

    if (is_string($_POST['key'])) { // <- IS THIS SAFE?

        $ufo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    } elseif (is_array($_POST['key'])) { // <- IS THIS SAFE?

        $ufo = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'key', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    }
}
```